# force new record to be inserted at the end of table?

Tags: mysql, database

whenever i delete a record and then insert new one, new record is inserted at the deleted index? how can i force new record to be inserted at the end of table?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to control the physical location of the row in the table (indices and tables being separate structs; acces being logical) ?  "Deleted Index" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the short answer is that you can't.  The slightly longer answer is that RDBMS technology is based on set-theory and that database tables, like sets, have no distinct order.  If you need it to be at the end when you query for that data, I would add an insertion_date field to the table and order by that field in your query.

Comment: or insertion_order autoincrement field

Comment: Rather than adding 'fields", why can't you SELECT... ORDER BY ?